# How do you pass multiple sql statements using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is what i want to do but with lots of records. When i try this i get this kind of error:[the error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOYE.png)

this is my currant php and when i submit it no record is added.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES (NULL, 'firstnameA', 'surnameA', 'example1@email.com', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES (NULL, 'firstnameB', 'surnameB', 'example@email.com', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    " ;
```

However this code works but i am only adding one record

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) VALUES (NULL, 'tom', 'walker', 'tom@walker.com', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
"
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to duplicate the values portion, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `reg_date`) 
   VALUES (NULL, 'tom', 'walker', 'tom@walker.com', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
   (NULL, 'bob', 'jones', 'bob@jones', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

Comment: remember the semicolon after the closing quote marks

Comment: Good point. Moved it, since it doesn't need to be inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_multi_query` check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php